# Adding numbers larger than long long in C++

Tags: c++

I want to add two numbers which is the largest values that a long long integer can hold; and print it. If I don't store the value of sum in a variable, I just print it using "cout" then will my computer will be able to print that? The code will be some what like this:

```
cout<<theLastValueOfLongLong + theLastValueOfLongLong;
```

I am assuming that a long long int is the largest primary variable type.

Comment: How about compiling that and trying it out?

Comment: This is probably undefined behaviour.

Comment: https://gmplib.org, the c++ version is called gmpxx i think

Comment: ^ if you are actually looking to represent larger numbers, the theory of what happens is UB and implementation defined, so not a very good question

Comment: You're probably not looking for `unsigned long long`  ;)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: You can't test Undefined Behavior. It may depend on silly uncontrollable things like whether a value came from a register, which in turn can depend on 18 optimization flags being combined in just the right way.

Comment: @MSalters You can still compile it and run to see that it actually won't produce the result wanted. Unless it's a totally strange environment where the UB would be "let's use a nonstandard type", which I have never heard any compiler doing. To me any question with "if I write this code and run it will it work?" is a "test it first, then ask" case anyway.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen What if you get the "correct" result 1000 times, and one in 1000 the UB kicks in? This happen quite often with pointers, although in the code above you probably won't get anything meaningful.

Comment: @vsoftco when the question says they want to add twice the max values, I'd be hard pressed to find that as the UB. It wasn't about adding two arbitrary numbers, then it would be different. But I would still run it and then ask if it's ok.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Fair enough.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: In this case, I'd expect the optimizer to detect that the addition is unreachable (it's correct to assume that unavoidable UB appears only in unreachable code), which means that it may eliminate the `cout<<` altogether. But optimizers are finicky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to overflow, then you need to use a "long integer" library, such as [Boost.Multiprecision.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/index.html) You can then perform arbitrary-long integer/f.p. operations, such as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>

int main()
{
   using namespace boost::multiprecision;

   cpp_int i; // multi-precision integer 

   i = std::numeric_limits<long long>::max();

   std::cout << "Max long long: " << i << std::endl; 
   std::cout << "Sum: " << i + i << std::endl;
}
```

In particular, Boost.Multiprecision is extremely easy to use and integrates "naturally" with C++ streams, allowing you to treat the type almost like a built-in one.

Comment: I didn't know about boost multiprecision, I have use gmp before, I will give it a whirl..

Comment: @GradyPlayer I like it a lot, as it's super simple to use, and I think it even wraps GMP for some more specialized tasks.

Answer (score 0):

No, at first it counts `(theLastValueOfLongLong + theLastValueOfLongLong)` (which causes overflow or freezes at max value available) and then it sends result into `cout.<<(long long)` operator

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as:

```
long long temp = theLastValueOfLongLong + theLastValueOfLongLong;
cout << temp;
```

`temp` will contain the result of the addition, which will be undefined because you get an overflow, and then it will cout that result what ever it's value is.

Answer (score 0):

Since `long long` is signed, the addition overflows. This is Undefined Behavior and anything may happen. It's *unlikely* to format your harddisk, especially in this simple case.

Once Undefined Behavior happens, you can't even count on `std::cout` working after that.