# long long variable becomes negative after I surpass 9-11 digits (C++)

Tags: c++, long-integer

**FIXED: The function that recieved the num variable and printed it on the calculator screen, recieved an "int" parameter**

I'm a beginner and trying to make a calculator on console. You have to type each number just like in real calculators and they appear on the left.

This is the function to get digits of the next input so I know how many 0's I have to run.

```
int getDigits(int number)
{
    int getDigits = 0;
    while (number) {
        number /= 10;
        getDigits++;
    }
    return getDigits;
}
```

**UPDATED GETDIGIT FUNCTION**

```
long long getDigits(long long number)
{
    long long getDigits = 0; //i know long long wasn't needed here
    while (number) {
        number /= 10;
        getDigits++;
    }
    return getDigits;
}
```

The main number displaying on the calculator screen is a long long "num" and it changes every do while iteration.

```
case 1:
        long long aux, aux2;
        cout << "Number: "; cin >> aux;
        aux2 = pow(10, getDigits(aux));
        num *= aux2;
        num += aux;
        break;
```

This just takes the second input places it on the right. It works perfectly but 
in this case when "num" excel 11 variables, it just becomes a negative number (i have no idea why, i did the operations manually and it should work fine). For example:

input: 1

num = 1

input: 2

num = 12

**but when it reaches 11 digits**

num = 12345678911

input = 1

num = -538112777 (instead of the 123456789111)

Why is this? all my variables are long long and should be enough, help really appreciated.

Comment: Your compiler should be complaining about `getDigits(aux)` as it could overflow.  If it is not you need to turn up your warning level.

Comment: It doesn't give me any warning. Could it still be the overflow you are talking about? or is there any other fix?

Comment: It could.  `getDigits` should take the same type you are passing to it.

Comment: Right, i just replaced the ints for long long but i still get the same error though, thanks for your help anyway

Comment: using `long` wont solve the problem on the long run, it will just take longer until you get an overflow

Comment: Oh, so really there aren't solutions for the overflow. I guess i'll just have to restrict the num to be 11 digits max.

Comment: `long long` should give you at least 18 decimal digits. If you're overflowing after 11, you're still doing something wrong. You told us that you "replaced the ints for long long", but you haven't shown us the updated code. Please leave the original code as it is in the question (there are answers based on it), but you can update the question to show your modified code.

Comment: If you want to work with numbers larger than what the built-in types support you can use a bignum library, like [GMP](https://gmplib.org).

Comment: `int` is 32 bits, and `long long` is 64 bits (on your platform at least, judging by description of your problem, but if you are writing portable C++ source and want to be sure about type size, rather use the `int32_t`/`int64_t` types from header `<cstdint>` instead of `int`/`long long`). Now the sign is usually implemented by two's complement method, so the top-most bit is sign bit, then if you keep incrementing positive value by one, at some point it will be big enough to overflow into the last (top) bit, at that point the output formatting will interpret that bit pattern as negative value.

Comment: Most of that in my previous comment is platform+compiler dependent, it's not set in standard and not required to be implemented this way. The standard just requires `int` to represent signed integer values, but doesn't care about underlying bit patterns used, that's implementation detail. But most(all?) of the common CPUs today use what I described (32 and 64 bit two's complement integers with top bit being sign for signed types). So it may be good for you to check binary numbers and understand why for example 16 bit integer (`short`) has maximum value `32767` and unsigned `65535`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding numbers larger than long long in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703844/adding-numbers-larger-than-long-long-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Integers in C++ have limited capacity.  Going beyond the capacity or range results in an overflow.

An overflow could *wrap around* and become negative.  The platform could generate an overflow exception.

Comment: So 11 digits is the maximum cap for my calculator?

Comment: The range is not about digits but value.  See [numerical limits](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits).

Answer (score 0):

Looking closely on your code, firstly

```
{
 int getDigits(int number)
{
 int getDigits = 0; 
 while (number) {
 number /= 10; 
 getDigits++; 
} 
return getDigits; 
}
```

You are passing `getDigits(long long aux)` to `getDigit` function thats is wrong.

Futhermore : why value become negative: the 8 bits are used to store character in which the RMB thats 8th from right to left and 1st from left to right when the value exceed  binary 127 the right most bit is set which makes the value negative. **The same happens to all the datatypes that are signed**

Comment: I know, i changed it to long long and still had the same issue. Do you know if anything could be done, or everything is badly structured?

Answer (score 0):

**FIXED: The function that recieved the num variable and printed it on the calculator screen, recieved an "int" parameter**